# Dspace 7.2 - Item Submission is extremely slow

Tags: dspace

I have just finished the upgrade to dspace 7.2, everything is migrated well and the navigation is pretty much smooth; except when I try to do a submission, the moment I click "deposit" it takes about 2 minutes for the submission to go through,

I tried different optimizations with no success,

Answer (score 0):

There have been so many different optimizations in the subsequent minor releases that it would be difficult to point the the specific issue you're affected by.

I would highly recommend to upgrade to 7.5 and see if your issue persists there. In that case, you'll know that you can search in 7.5 (7.6 unreleased) specific issues.

But I hope that your minor upgrade to 7.5 will fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the email settings. It seems as it try to send a submission confirmation email and wait until timeout.